# mongoose select with !boolean or boolean and past date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Just wondering how I would do the following selection:

Schema:

```
Item: {
  ...
  premium: {
    isPremium: Boolean,
    expiryDate: Date
  }
}
```

It should return all items where premium.isPremium == false OR ( premium.isPremium == true AND premium.expiryDate <= currentDate ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Item.statics = {
    getPremium: function (currentDate) {
        return this.find().or([{'premium.isPremium': false}, {'premium.isPremium': true, 'premium.expiryDate': {$lte: currentDate}}]).exec()
    }
}
```

Comment: This only seems to be doing one or the other, not combining them. If the first option returns something, the other is never run.

Comment: You forgot to wrap the or values in square brackets []. I added them and it seems to be working now. Update your answer and I will mark it correct.